# Why is it useful to slice an entire array?

Tags: arrays, rust

I found some code in [an in-progress tutorial for Glium](http://tomaka.github.io/glium/tutorials/03-colors.html) that seems to take a slice of an entire array:

```
use std::io::Cursor;
let image = image::load(Cursor::new(&include_bytes!("/path/to/image.png")[..]),
                        image::PNG).unwrap();
```

`include_bytes!` appears to load the given file into memory and then return a reference to it as a static array. What I'm confused about it why you would then take a reference to a slice of the entire array before passing it to `Cursor::new`.

Comment: @Veedrac what alternative would you use? `Read` is only implemented for a handful of instances of `Cursor<T>`, but the constructor allows any type.

Comment: @Shepmaster I meant `&<expr>[..]`. [`include_bytes!` claims to already return a `&'static [u8]`.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes!.html)

Comment: @Veedrac great point, let's see if we can [clarify the docs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/28289) ^_^.

Answer (score 6):

`include_bytes!` produces something of type `&[u8; N]`, so the `&…[..]` wrapping is to get a `&[u8]` out of it.

Comment: Perhaps add [an example](http://is.gd/D8wv0T) or describe why one might want to do this?

Comment: If this was the case though, wouldn't `&include_bytes!` be sufficient?

Comment: @louis058: no, `&include_bytes!()` would just be `&&[u8; N]`. You’re needing to get it as a regular slice so that the I/O stuff of `std::io::{Cursor, Read, Seek}` works on it.

Answer (score 4):

It is idiomatic Rust to write functions that take a slice as input because then that function can be used with any collection that can be sliced.